# Angular ng-for Odd/Even Scenario

Tags: html, angular-2+

I just want to create masonry vertical layout with two divider ``` .card-lef`` and ```.card-right`. Anyone have an idea to place `#cardTemplate` in left or right based on data Odd/Even? Or maybe in my .ts separate odd/even array?

HTML:

```
<ng-template let-data="data" #cardTemplate>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: It's likely that the even-odd distinction should be made entirely in CSS, not in Angular.

Comment: @200_success yeah it should on css part, but how to get it when we need vertical masonry layout.